# i want to make a text carry the textfield after i have searched for it

Tags: flutter

i have an if statement with 2 else i want the third else to carry the controller of the textfield,

```
ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        if (widget.isChatList) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                userData: widget.data,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (widget.data.userId != userid) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => VisitorProfile(data: visitorData)));
        } else {
        //This is where i want when i tap the users name it takes the search textfield
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
      },
```

i have an if statement with 2 else i want the third else to carry a controller

Answer (score 1):

try this
**Navigator.pop(context, textController.text);**